# Manipulating Meteor cursors

Tags: javascript, meteor, cursor

I am writing a Meteor method that searches all of my collections for keywords. One stumbling point I am having is how to manipulate/concat returned cursors like arrays. Is it best to turn them into arrays concat and manipulate them from there, or is there a way to concat/manipulate cursors?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cursor can't be concatenated because a cursor is not a data structure, it is a data accessor.
It just says **how** to access data.

If you need to concatenate cursors, you can either store the data in a new collection/change a publication to aggregate, or you can `fetch` them and concatenate the resulting arrays.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know fetch returned an array. Is there a pro to using cursors then? Why wouldn't I just always call `fetch` so I can get it in an array?

Comment: Cursors are really useful for a whole lot of manipulations, including server<->client communication and SpaceBars helpers. More [in the doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/foreach).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use

```
var array = [];
cursor.map(function( element ){
  //test element for keyword       
  if( isKeyword( element ) ){
    //add stuff to array
    array.push( element );
  }
});
```

[Doc for map](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/map)

Manipulation of a cursor makes no sense so you have to bring your own array to store the found data.

But what is this cursor? It is a mongo cursor and is defined  [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor):

> A pointer to the result set of a query. Clients can iterate through a cursor to retrieve results. By default, cursors timeout after 10 minutes of inactivity.

More information  [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#cursors).